# Inconsistent behavior with `empty` std ranges view depending on type

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Consider the following code snippet:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
};

struct B
{
    B(void *) {};
};

template<class T, class R>
std::vector<T> foo(R &&range)
{
    return std::vector<T> {
        std::ranges::begin(range), 
        std::ranges::end(range)
        };
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo<A>(std::views::empty<A>).size() << "\n";
    std::cout << foo<B>(std::views::empty<B>).size() << "\n";
}
```

It correctly prints `0` on the first line and incorrectly prints `2` on the second line on GCC 11.2 (https://godbolt.org/z/s6aoTGbr4) and MSVC 19.30.30705 (Visual Studio 2022 17.0).

Apparently in the second case `std::views::empty` view produces iterators that causes constructor taking initializer list to be selected.

Changing `std::vector<T> { ... }` to `std::vector<T> ( ... )` fixes this, but I wonder if it is actually a bug in implementation (or even definition) of the `empty` view?

Comment: iterators can be pointers, and your `B` type is constructible from pointers so it makes sense that this can happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you should be wary of list-initialization! In particular, this syntax:

```cpp
std::vector<T>{ ... }
```

should *only* (!!) be used when you're specifically trying to invoke the `std::initializer_list<T>` constructor, and specifically providing elements to the `vector` and not in any other case. Like this one, where you're not trying to call that constructor.

---

The issue is that in list-initialization, the `std::initializer_list` constructor is strongly preferred. If it is at all viable, it is chosen first. In this case, we are trying to construct a `vector<B>` from two pointers to `B` (that's the iterator type for `empty<B>`). A `B` is constructible from a `B*` (via the `void*` constructor), which makes the `std::initializer_list<B>` constructor a viable candidate, which means it's selected.

As a result, you get a `vector<B>` with two `B`s, each constructed form a null pointer.

For `A`, there's no such viable constructor, so you fallback to normal initialization, which will select the iterator pair constructor, giving you an empty `vector<A>`.

The fix here is to use `()`s when you initialize, since that's actually what you intend to do.

Comment: Aha, so this is just another case of this particularly evil vector constructor overload hiding in unexpected places... In my case it was a vector of `CComVariant`, a legacy class from Windows SDK that has implicit constructors taking pointers and an attempt to use an `empty` view.